# Converting CommonJS to AMD

Tags: node.js, requirejs, amd, commonjs

I have a simple CommonJS module published on NPM and Bower that basically just looks like this:

```
  function Foo(){}

    module.exports = new Foo();
```

now the easiest way to convert to AMD format would be just to publish a second version that was AMD compatible like so:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {

    function Foo(){}

    module.exports = new Foo();

});
```

but I thought there was a way you can shim the CommonJS module using requirejs.config like so:

```
requirejs.config({

   paths:{
    'foo':'assets/vendor/foo'
   },
   shim:{

     'foo' :{
       exports: 'Foo'
      }
   }
});
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I figure that the shim tool does the wrapping that I did above for you, but I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Problem

`shim` cannot do as much as you want it to do. When RequireJS evaluates the symbol you give in `exports`, it evaluates it in the global space. So using `exports` works fine if you can access the variable you want to export from the global space. If library `foo` exports `Foo` into the global space, that works fine.

What you are trying to do is have a module that exports its API through `module` work with a `shim`. This cannot work because RequireJS cannot guess that the module being loaded requires that a global `module` object be already available to the module being loaded. In the simplest case, loading such module will result in a `ReferenceError` because `module` does not exist. There would be ways to fake the `module.exports` thing that would work in the most trivial cases but it would not work as a general solution.

#### A Solution

You can use `r.js` to convert files that are written in the CommonJS format to what RequireJS needs. It is [documented here](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html#autoconversion). The documentation gives the following synopsis:

```
node r.js -convert path/to/commonjs/modules/ path/to/output
```

You should also read [this part](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js#convert-commonjs-modules) of the README for some caveats.